# Not able to reset AD password from Java using LDAP

Tags: java, ldap, change-password

I'm trying to reset user password from java using LDAP. Code as below :

```
System.out.println("Inside Password Reset");
//String Password = Long.toHexString(Double.doubleToLongBits(Math.random()));
String Password = "Password5";
ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[1];
Attribute mod0 = new BasicAttribute("userpassword", Password);
mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, mod0);
System.out.println("Updated Password: " + Password);
dctx.modifyAttributes("cn=xxx,ou=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xxx",mods);
System.out.println("Attributes to be modified are :" + mods);
```

Doesn't give any error but when I try to login to that user using the new password it doesn't work.

Comment: You may need to supply the old password and the new password in separate `ModificationItems`, one to be deleted and he other to be added. Strange you didn't get an error though.

Comment: Gives me LDAP: error code 53 - 00002077: SvcErr: DSID-03190E49, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM) error. My AD is non ssl

Comment: This is caused when you don't use SSL in your LDAP connection and AD enforces SSL connection.

Comment: @RohanKadu Is there a way we can do it without SSL connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enabled SSL Connection to my AD and was able to reset the password.